# Convert LINQ to SQL result to DataTable or DataView VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql, datatable

I need a temporary DataTable or DataView made by LINQ to SQL result. but i cant prepare them based on L2S method in VB.Net 2010. is it possible without using loops?

And a basic question! What is the structure of L2S results? I was thinking it must be a DataTable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Linq to Dataset. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921.aspx

```
' Query the SalesOrderHeader table for orders placed 
'  after August 8, 2001.

Dim query = _
From order In orders.AsEnumerable() _
Where order.Field(Of DateTime)("OrderDate") > New DateTime(2001, 8, 1) _
Select order

' Create a table from the query.
Dim boundTable As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable()
```

Hope, It should Work.